# How to use a native FileDialog without blocking a background worker QThread in python with PySide6?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyside, qthread

I am building an application in which data from an external device is permanently read in. The communication to the external device is outsourced to a separate background worker thread (QThread).
Now I want to be able to open a file in the application with an OS native FileDialog.
In PyQt/PySide this is done with the static method [QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtforpython-5.12/PySide2/QtWidgets/QFileDialog.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName) according to the documentation.
It turned out that not only the MainThread but also the background thread is blocked by the modal dialog.

Is it possible to use a native FileDialog without blocking the background thread?

Here is an example code. The background thread should print() the current time and a counter every 200ms.
In my tests the output is interrupted as long as the dialog is open.

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *

from PySide6 import QtCore

import time
import debugpy
import asyncio
import threading


class Worker(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def start(self):
        print("Worker started.")
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        debugpy.debug_this_thread()
        print("Worker runníng")
        count = 0
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            print(f"{count} : run() {time.time()}")
            count += 1


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        btn = QPushButton("modal OpenFileDialog")
        btn.pressed.connect(self.open_file_dialog)

        layout.addWidget(btn)

        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        self.show()

        self._thread = QThread()
        self._thread.setObjectName("WorkerThread")
        self._worker = Worker()
        self._worker.moveToThread(self._thread)
        self._thread.started.connect(self._worker.start)
        self._thread.start()

    def open_file_dialog(self):
        print("open modal dialog")
        name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File")
        print("close modal dialog")


app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

Output:

```
Worker started.  
Worker runníng  
0 : run() 1642941117.861353  
1 : run() 1642941118.0631094  
2 : run() 1642941118.2644503  
3 : run() 1642941118.46529  
4 : run() 1642941118.6673386  
5 : run() 1642941118.8683393  
6 : run() 1642941119.069339  
open modal dialog  
7 : run() 1642941128.8170435  
close modal dialog  
8 : run() 1642941129.0190463  
9 : run() 1642941129.2205596  
10 : run() 1642941129.421668  
11 : run() 1642941129.6226685  
12 : run() 1642941129.8236694  
13 : run() 1642941130.0247314
```

Comment: The main thread is not blocked, it just doesn't accept input events. An interesting thing I noticed, though: if the main thread has a timer that temporarily "distracts" the dialog's event loop (for instance, updating a simple label with the current time), the worker thread *sometimes* gets called (depending on GIL, I suppose). This seems a bug to me, as in PyQt it works as expected

Comment: For me, this is a purely PySide2/6 bug which only affects the static functions. If I create an instance of QFileDialog and open it with `show/exec`, the problem goes away. I can only test on archlinux, though, so the behaviour might be different on other platforms.

Comment: @ekhumoro a QFileDialog instance with show/exec call does not create a OS native dialog. It uses a Qt designed (ugly) dialog at least in my tests. This is also the documented behaviour.

Comment: @Batuu Yes, but I don't have a native file-dialog on my platform, so that's not relevant. I was just pointing out that the bug seems to be specific to the static function itself (or, rather, pyside's handling of it).

Comment: @Batuu PS: can you confirm that this problem only affects PySide (and not PyQt) on your system, and also state the platform you are testing on.

Comment: @ekhumoro : yes I can confirm that. PyQt6 do not block when calling the static method to get a native dialog. I am running my tests under Win10 x64.

Comment: I reported the bug to the PySide development team. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1792